# MicroServices Architecture

Tags: java, scala, lambda, soa, microservices

I have few questions related to MicroServices Architecture.

- What should be the granularity of the MicroServices? We have tables in both Relational and NoSQL Databases. Should there be one service per table? I think services per datasource would make more sense, but then it would be SOA.
- If we create bunch of MicroServices, should we also provide client libraries to facilitate consumption of services? Or just let caller use any REST library to make calls. One way or another, it sounds a lot of work though.
- Should three be one GIT repo for each MicroService?
- Is it ok to deploy multiple MicroServices in same EC2 instance?
- I would imagine deploying MicroServices on AWS Lambda would be perfect, but then the whole application would be just bunch of Lambda functions. Not to mention the tight coupling with AWS Lambdas. Has anyone implemented MicroServices on Lambdas? I'd appreciate any feedback on this.

Answer (score 4):

Implementation of Microservices is often different from system to system or developer to developer. However some of the essential characteristics of microservices are,

- Small focus (do one thing and to do that one thing well)
- Loosely Coupled (Operates independently with one another)
- Language Neutral
- Bounded Context (do not need to know the implementation of other microservices)

We can make use of AWS lambda in achieving above characteristics. But maintaining and managing Lambda endpoints could be tricky and often a hassle. You can make use of [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/) to easily manage lambda functions. You can define a service configuration in simple YAML format, and the framework creates a CloudFromation stack and deploy it.

With serverless framework you can define multiple services. Each service could be small focus, loosely coupled, language neutral and bounded context. Eg: User CRUD, Email Notifications, Scheduled Jobs etc... When you deploy services with Serverless Framework, it creates different API Gateways linked with respective lambdas. You can make use of API Gateway endpoints to interact with each service.

As you have mentioned a lambda could be linked with other AWS services. But i think,  as long as it does not depend upon other microservices and has a clearly defined integration points to services like Dynamodb table or a S3 bucket we can make use of Lambda to develop microservices.